# minitalk project using Rust | Communication between process using UNIX Signals

Tags: rust, unix

I am trying to build minitalk project from 42 school using Rust instead of C. This is a communication program between a client and a server. Both are process. To achieve this I am only allowed to use UNIX Signals SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2. While I got help to achieve this, I would appreciate an external point of view for the below code.

*server.rs*

```
use signal_hook::{iterator::Signals, consts::{SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2}};
use std::error::Error;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::time::{Instant, Duration};
use std::thread;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let pid = std::process::id();
    println!("Server PID: {}", pid);

    let message = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));
    let last_received = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Instant::now()));
    let mut signals = Signals::new(&[SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2])?;

    let message_clone = Arc::clone(&message);
    let last_received_clone = Arc::clone(&last_received);
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut byte = 0;
        let mut bit_count = 0;
        for sig in signals.forever() {
            let mut last_received = last_received_clone.lock().unwrap();
            *last_received = Instant::now();
            drop(last_received);

            let mut message = message_clone.lock().unwrap();
            match sig {
                SIGUSR1 => byte |= 1 << bit_count,
                SIGUSR2 => (),
                _ => unreachable!(),
            }
            bit_count += 1;
            if bit_count == 8 {
                message.push(byte);
                byte = 0;
                bit_count = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    loop {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
        let last_received = last_received.lock().unwrap();
        if last_received.elapsed() >= Duration::from_millis(50) {
            let mut message = message.lock().unwrap();
            if !message.is_empty() {
                let message_str = String::from_utf8_lossy(&message);
                println!("{}", message_str);
                message.clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*client.rs*

```
use std::process::Command;
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let pid = &args[1];
    let message = &args[2];

    for byte in message.bytes() {
        for i in 0..8 {
            let bit = (byte >> i) & 1;
            let signal = if bit == 1 { "SIGUSR1" } else { "SIGUSR2" };
            Command::new("kill")
                .arg(format!("-{}", signal))
                .arg(pid)
                .output()
                .expect("Failed to send signal");
        }
    }
}
```

*Cargo.toml*

```
[package]
name = "minitalk"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
nix = "0.27.1"
signal-hook = "0.3.17"
libc = "0.2"

[[bin]]
name = "server"
path = "./src/server.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "client"
path = "./src/client.rs"
```

Execution:
Open two terminal inside src directory (one to execute the server, one for client).

1st terminal:
`cargo run --bin server`
Server PID: "{x}"

2nd terminal:
`cargo run --bin client server_pid hello`

hello will print on the stdout of server bin.

While this work as expected, I would like to have your opinion on this program as this is in Rust and not C. Thanks

Comment: Not worth a whole review but if you put `server.rs` and `client.rs` [into `src/bin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#binaries) you don't need the sections in your `Cargo.toml` because you conform to the standard [project layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html)

Answer (score 2):

This code is [racy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).
It does not appear capable of reliably sending a bytestream.

---

## map

```
            let signal = if bit == 1 { "SIGUSR1" } else { "SIGUSR2" };
```

That `if` expression is nice enough.
But consider using a HashMap instead.

---

## syscall vs spawn a child

```
            Command::new("kill")
                .arg(format!("-{}", signal))
                .arg(pid)
```

zomg, that fork + exec seems expensive.
Just send a signal from within the current process.

Of course, "expensive" might actually be a good thing,
as the delay masks other issues,
and gives the scheduler a chance to run.
I was expecting to see a call to signal() followed by
a call to sleep(), giving the server a chance to receive the signal.
Or, much better, a call to acquire a mutex or manipulate a condition variable
so we know the server is *ready* to receive the next bit.

---

## delete dead code

```
    let last_received_clone = Arc::clone(&last_received);
```

Those two variables appear to be related to some "display a timestamp"
debugging code that was deleted prior to review.
Now that you're getting ready to merge to `main`,
it is the right time to tidy up vestiges of debugs.

---

## magic numbers

```
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
        ...
        if last_received.elapsed() >= Duration::from_millis(50) {
```

The `1` is for yielding control to the scheduler, fine. Maybe `0` would suffice.

The `50` needs a [name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))
and an explanation.
I imagine that on a certain host it allows server to mostly win the races.
It's unclear how it was arrived at, and how one would choose an
appropriate constant on a Cray or a Raspberry Pi.

---

## race

Here is the heart of the issue:

```
        for sig in signals.forever() {
```

The trouble is that on unix / linux systems,
there's no queueing of signals.
For example client might send a pair of SIGUSR1's,
yet just a *single* SIGUSR1 is picked up in this loop.
The OS is allowed to coalesce rapidly sent signals.

How to fix?

1. Use IPC that makes appropriate guarantees, such as a muxtex, or
2. have client await a handshake signal before sending its next signal.

For the current (racy) code,
consider appending a validation checksum.
Or allow re-sync like a UART does by sending start + stop bits.
Or send redundant [FEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_code) data.

---

This code does not yet appear to achieve its design goals.